# Using graphs generated my Munin in a Swing application

Tags: swing, graph, munin

I'm able to generate a usage statistics graph in my browser for a particular PC using [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). The problem is that I want to use the graphs in a Swing application where the graphs will  be displayed. Is there any way to do so? What are the other options available to generate the same graphs on Swing? Do I have to manually generate the readings and plot the graph accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is written in `perl`, it should possible to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to evoke the desired graph. A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984445/interaction-between-java-app-and-python-app/1985463#1985463).

Alternatively, it may be possible to install Munin locally and fetch the image as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170134/java-swing-jcomponent-size/4170233#4170233).

Comment: Implementation details of the first approach would depend on a thorough understanding of Munin which I do not posses.

Comment: @trashgod- Thanks for your time. As you said, I looked into munin and looks like the graphs are generated by displaying a png image in the browser which has to be refreshed continuously. I would like to display a continuous graph. Anyway, I'll also look into the links you've suggested.