# JavaFX java.io.IOException "uptime": error=13, permission denied - Running program as regular user

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, permissions

I'm writing a program for work and a certain part of the code uses `Process` and `ProcessBuilder` to run some system commands.

I'm developing it in a Linux Mint machine but the program will run in Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME.

When I build the maven project as javafx:jlink (because I'm going to build it as a .deb package) and run the `bin/app` script that gets created. I get this error in the console.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "uptime": error=13, Permission denied
```

I've already searched other threads and they all say the same thing that I have to give the user running the program permissions to that executable with `chmod u+x /usr/bin/uptime`. It doesn't work.

Originally this part of the code was using `Process`, switched to `ProcessBuilder` and still didn't do anything. I even went as far as to make the user owner of `/usr/bin/uptime` and I still get that error.

This is what I'm currently working with:

```
// Set Uptime
try{
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("uptime","-p").start();
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    uptime = new String(in.readAllBytes());
    p.destroy();
}catch (IOException err){
    System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

The only difference that I can think of is that in my Linux Mint machine, my user is Administrator where as the test machine, the user is a regular user.

I disabled AppArmor thinking it was causing issues, checked `journalctl -xe` to see if anything odd came up and even checked `/var/log/syslog` but no errors either.

If I open a regular terminal as this user, I can run these commands perfectly fine. It's getting a bit hard to pinpoint where this is giving me trouble. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985463/230513), specify [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) to see more about the error. For example, on my platform,

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder()
    .command("/usr/bin/uptime", "-p")
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
    .start();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
System.out.println(new String(in.readAllBytes()));
```

Tells me this:

```
uptime: illegal option -- p
usage: uptime
```

Removing the unsupported option, produces the expected output. As an aside the full path can be determined by running `which uptime`.

Comment: I added this to 2 different `ProcessBuilder`s and none of them have given any other errors aside from the stacktrace.

Comment: Try the full path returned by `which uptime`.

Comment: Tried that as well. Still nothing... I did run my project on the actual machine that we will be  deploying the software to and running it from the IDE, it loaded everything just fine. I wonder if there's some Java permission i need to setup or something. As mentioned, I'm building the project as JLink, so I wonder if that has something to do with it...

Comment: Sorry, I've not used [tag:jlink], but it's hard to imagine `uptime` requiring more privilege than launching the JVM. Can you launch the application's JAR directly on the target to see more?

Comment: On my development machine (which is Linux Mint) I built the project with JLink and the app ran just fine. I then copied the files built on my dev machine and sent it to the production machine in a ZIP and it launched just fine! I think its something funky GitHub is doing when building the project using Workflows... But glad its not an actual Linux Permission issue because I have changed so many permissions and nothing helped, lol. Thanks though!

Comment: I've encountered such problems based on file permissions, line terminators, etc. Glad it's working; you might update the question to reflect the difficulty reproducing the problem.